# Do depleted units cost full upkeep costs?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

Do units who have sustained casualties in battle cost the full amount in upkeep or do they only cost a fraction?

For example if a unit lost half it's men in combat, are it's upkeep costs reduced by 50% or do you still pay full upkeep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both in Rome Total War 1 and 2 you get reduced costs.

So if a unit of 100 spearmen has an upkeep of 200 and 45 people die, the final upkeep is 110.